# What keywords should I use in a for-loop when using if-statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

Let's assume that we have a for-loop that will loop through a collection or array of Strings. In that case, I am searching for a specific keyword (ex. hey) here's how I usually achieve that:

```
for (String result : strings)
{
    if (result == "hey")
    {
        // Do something with that.
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, the question arises from that code snippet is, **should I place a keyword (return or break) when the if-statement returns true so the loop will not continue?** If not, what will happen and what's the correct way of going about it.

Edit: What happens when you use break and return? What's the difference?

Comment: What happens with return and break in two different situations?

Comment: If that's how you normally "achieve" string comparisons, you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Well one breaks out of the loop and one returns from the method... it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put your code inside a method:

```
private void foo() 
{
    for (String result : strings)
    {
        if (result.equals("hey"))
        {
            // Do something with that.
            break;
        }
    }
    bar();
}
```

If you use `break;`, the loop will terminate and `bar` will be reached. If you use `return`, the method will terminate and `bar` won't be executed.

Note that comparing strings should be done using [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), `==` compares references and not content.

Comment: I got you, thanks for that example. And from now on I'll be using the equals method on Strings. So the loop will end once a result is found?

Comment: @Thanos If you want it to, use `break` or `return`, depending on whether you want to terminate the method or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'll choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the word can only be found once you can surely place an break; statement so the loop won't continue after finding the match.

If you can have more than one match and you want the if block to be executed for each of those matches you should NOT put the break statement since it will stop the execution of the loop after the first match is found.